# Coypu freezing application

Tags: webautomation, coypu

I'm trying a very simple code using Coypu but my app just freezes without any exceptions.

I've setup a new C# project and installed Coypu using nuget, the application bin folder seems to contain all the necessary files as well:

- chromedriver.exe ([downloaded](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.15/chromedriver_win32.zip))
- Coypu.dll
- WebDriver.dll
- WebDriver.Support.dll.

**Sample:**

```
var sessionConfiguration = new SessionConfiguration
{
  Driver = typeof(SeleniumWebDriver),
  Browser = Coypu.Drivers.Browser.Chrome
};

using (var browser = new BrowserSession())//Freezes here
{
  browser.Visit("http://www.google.com");//Never reaches
}

MessageBox.Show("Done");//Never reaches
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the sessionConfiguration  object to your BrowserSession.

```
var sessionConfiguration = new SessionConfiguration
{
  Driver = typeof(SeleniumWebDriver),
  Browser = Coypu.Drivers.Browser.Chrome
};

using (var browser = new BrowserSession(sessionConfiguration))
{
  browser.Visit("http://www.google.com");
}

MessageBox.Show("Done");
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
var browser = new BrowserSession(new SessionConfiguration()
{
   Driver = typeof(SeleniumWebDriver),
   Browser = Coypu.Drivers.Browser.Chrome
});

browser.Visit("http://www.google.com");
browser.FillIn("lst-ib").With("hakuna matata");
browser.ClickButton("btnG");
```